# search keyword using expression

Tags: java

I'm trying to implement this test in order to search text into sentence:

```
    @Test
    void justAnExample() {
        List<String> list = findPhrasesInDocument("some test located into long program", List.of("test", "into", "long program"));

        System.out.print(String.join("\n", list));
    }

    List<String> findPhrasesInDocument(String keywordToFind, List<String> phrases) {
        List<String> foundPhrases = new ArrayList<>();

        String regex = String.format("\b%s\b", keywordToFind);
        // Creating a pattern object
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
        // Matching the compiled pattern in the String
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(keywordToFind);

        for (String phrase : phrases) {

            if (matcher.find()) {
                foundPhrases.add(phrase);
            }
        }
        return foundPhrases;
    }
```

But when I run the program there is no output printed. Do you know where I'm wrong?

Comment: You're looking for `keywordToFind` in `keywordToFind`. You're then repeatedly find()ing which doesn't work. `\b` isn't what you think it is (you want `\\b`). Without using `Pattern.quote`, this code is going to fail if 'thing to find' includes any regex relevant symbols. These feel like things a simple debug act will trivially find, which leads me to think your real question is: I do not quite understand the regex API or how regexes work, or, "How do I debug code", which are different questions than this.

Comment: Can you show me code example, please?

Comment: an example of how to debug your code? That's more a thing for tutorials, not so much a stack overflow question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all it looks you are doing it the wrong way around. From the signature I would expect that the first argument is the document (the haystack) and the second argument is the list of substrings you want to find (the needles).

**Update**: as rzwitserloot pointed out in the comments, my original answer did not cover the detail that only whole words shall be reported as match - so substring is not enough. Here is the updated version:

```java
    List<String> findPhrasesInDocument(String document, List<String> phrases) {
        return phrases
            .stream()
            .filter(p -> document.matches(
                String.format(
                    "(.*\\s)?%s(\\s.*)?",
                    Pattern.quote(p)
                )
            ))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
```

The regular expression is build with the following ideas in mind:

1. The phrase can be preceeded by an arbitrary string which is separated with a space.
2. The phrase can be succeeded by an arbitrary string which is separated with a space.
3. The phrase can appear at the start or the end of the document, which makes 1) and 2) optional.
4. The phrase itself must be taken literally, so we have to quote it.

**End of Update**

Also a quick side-note regarding your test. It looks like it is supposed to be a unit test. As such, it should actually *assert* something. In this case it should assert that all three items from the input list are also returned as found. You should add more tests that are also covering the case that a phrase is not found (and one for the case that all phrases are not found).

Comment: The question is really low effort so I don't want to downvote this, but you're eliding over a ton of stuff here. OP wants to include the word breaks around the phrases, and 'should assert something' could probably do with an example. But, that's caveatted a bit with: This entire question isn't appropriate for SO, as it's just typos and simple bugs.

Comment: @rzwitserloot I'm waiting quite impatiently to see your high quality answer

Comment: @UniversE bad news. I tried `List<String> list = findPhrasesInDocument("adventure dream", List.of("dre", "into", "long program"));` and I get match for `dre`. Any idea why?

Comment: @PeterPenzov I wasn't planning on writing one.

Comment: @PeterPenzov sort of a combination of "improperly defining the expected result" on your side, and "improperly reading between the lines" on my side. I think I do now understand a bit better what you want. I cannot update my answer right now, but in the next one or two days I will.

Comment: @PeterPenzov sorry, took me way longer than I wanted to come back to this question, but I have finally updated my answer.